# Magento 2 shipping method radio button not display selected on checkout

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, knockoutjs, radio-fields

I have customized the checkout step to make **one step** checkout. everything is working fine but when I click on select shipping method radio button functionality is working but radio button not display selected. but when i click on radio button label **Eg: Flat Rate** radio button will display selected.

I didn't understand what is wrong when clicking on radio button not display selected but click on radio button label display as selected.

Below is my **.html** overridden file which is responsible for shipping method HTML render. can anyone help to short out this issue?

```
<tr class="row" data-bind="click: $parent.selectShippingMethod.bind($parent)">
    <td class="col col-method">
        <!-- ko ifnot: method.error_message -->
        <!-- ko if: $parent.rates().length == 1 -->
        <input class="radio"
               type="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {
                            checked: $parent.rates().length == 1,
                            'value' : method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                            'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code,
                            'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                         }" />
        <label class="label"><span data-bind=""></span></label>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!--ko ifnot: ($parent.rates().length == 1)-->
        <input type="radio"
               data-bind="
                        value: method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                        checked: $parent.isSelected,
                        attr: {
                            'id': 's_method_' + method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                            'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                        },
                        click: $parent.selectShippingMethod"
               class="radio"/>
               <label class="label"><span data-bind=""></span></label>
        <!--/ko-->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </td>
    <td class="col col-price">
        <span class="price" data-bind="text: $parent.formatPrice(method.amount)"></span>
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </td>

    <td class="col col-method"
            data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>

    <td class="col col-carrier"
            data-bind="text: method.carrier_title, attr: {'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nemesv.

There is an issue in **Ajax** when i select shipping method i called ajax **setShippingInformation** so in a knockout case of ajax By default, Knockout will prevent the **click** event from taking any default action.

if you do want to let the default **click** action proceed, just return true from your click handler function.

See the detailed answer from here: [knockout js radio button click event reset selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250137/knockout-js-radio-button-click-event-reset-selection)